# Disabled input until check box is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a form input with a prepended check box and I want this input to be disabled until the checkbox is selected. How would I go about doing this?

This is my input:

```
  <div class="form-group ">
                    <label class="control-label" for="date">Student</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <input type="checkbox">
                      </span>
                      <input id="prependedcheckbox" name="prependedcheckbox" class="form-control"
                      type="text" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                  </div
```

[This](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/?#disabled-states) is an example of the disabled state I'm talking about.

Comment: And how are you prepending the checkbox, show us what you're doing !

Comment: so add change event and set the disabled attribute....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you do it with JQuery(Remember to add an id to the checkbox):

```
$(function() {
  $inp = $("#prependedcheckbox");
  $cb = $("#checkbox");
  $inp.prop('disabled', true);

  $cb.on('change', function() {
    if ($cb.is(':checked')) {
      $inp.prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $inp.prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });

});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jajtj5dc/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you want simple javascript, you can add disabled attribute to your input element then javascript it like:

```js
var checkbox = document.getElementById("radio");
function validator() {
  if (checkbox.checked == false) {
    document.getElementById('prependedcheckbox').disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('prependedcheckbox').disabled = false;
  }
}

checkbox.addEventListener('click', validator);
```

```html
<div class="form-group ">
    <label class="control-label" for="date">Student</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <input type="checkbox" id="radio">
        </span>
        <input id="prependedcheckbox" name="prependedcheckbox" class="form-control"
                      type="text" placeholder="" disabled />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add an attribute `disabled` to your HTML input, then check if the checkbox is **checked**, and then enable the input. The following is done using jQuery:

```
$(":checkbox").change(function() {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) $("#prependedcheckbox").prop("disabled", false);
    else $("#prependedcheckbox").prop("disabled", true);
}
```

And your HTML input having an added attribute `disabled`:

```
<input id="prependedcheckbox" name="prependedcheckbox" class="form-control"
    type="text" placeholder="" disabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('input:checkbox').click(function () {
    if ($('input:checkbox').is(":checked")) {
       $("#prependedcheckbox").attr("disabled", "disabled")
    }
    else {
         $("#prependedcheckbox").removeAttr("disabled")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made that.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="selected">

$('#selected').on('click', function(){
        if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
            $('#prependedcheckbox').attr('disabled', true);
    }else{
          $('#prependedcheckbox').attr('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

[This is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jorge182/n546ycuv/1/)